# String regex for a particular format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings in the following format `name1 <email1@email.com>`. How can I use regex to pull only the name1 part out?
Also, how might I be able to do this if I had multiple such names and emails, say `name1 <email1@email.com>, name2 <email2@email.com>`?

Comment: Are the emails actually surrounded by `< >`?

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with `(\w+)\s<.*?>(?:,\s)?` (see on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F6vOZe/2)), which relies on the fact that emails are surrounded by `< >`, and customize it as you see fit.

**Note** that this regex does not specifically look for emails, just for text surrounded by `< >`.

Don't fall down [the rabbit hole of trying to specifically match emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression).

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s<.*?>(?:,\s)?')
string = 'name1 <email1@email.com>, name2 <email2@email.com>'
```

print([match for match in regex.findall(string)])

outputs

```
['name1', 'name2']
```

Comment: This actually works better for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `split`:

```
In [164]: s = 'name1 <email1@email.com>, name2 <email2@email.com>'
In [166]: [i.split()[0] for i in s.split(',')]
Out[166]: ['name1', 'name2']
```

If you have just one name:

```
In [161]: s = 'name1 <email1@email.com>'
In [163]: s.split()[0]
Out[163]: 'name1'
```

Comment: I thought to do this too, but it only works if there are not additional spaces, which I doubt is guaranteed; indeed a regex about `<` would be much cleaner!

Comment: I don't think the emails are surrounded by `<>`. Its just a way of representing.

Comment: @ti7 `str.split` will behave the same if there are multiple spaces. `'name1 <someemail>'.split()` returns the same output as `'name1            <someemail>'.split()`

Comment: Yes, `str.split` by default handles whitespaces.

Comment: obviously, but it will not work if the structure is like `first, last <email@sld.tld>` (which "real" emails frequently are) - the OP did not state this, but it'll be the case for any real-world collection

Comment: The emails are surrounded by `<>`, which is why I quoted the whole thing.

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

name = re.search(r'(?<! <)\w+', 'name1 <email@email.com>')

print(name.group(0))

>>> name1
```

Explanation:

(?<!...) is called a negative lookbehind assertion. I added ' <' into the ... as you are looking for the string that precedes the '<' of the email.

```
re.search(r'(?<!...), string_to_search)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

---

Edit/Forgot:

To search strings with multiple:

```
import re

regex = r"\w+([?<! <])"

multi_name = "name1 <email@email.com>, name2 <email@email.com>"
    
matches = re.finditer(regex, multi_name, re.MULTILINE)
    
for group, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(f"Match: {match.group()}")

>>> name1
>>> name2
```